# VB Excel Deleting Rows On A Specified Value Being In a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
    For Each c In oSheet.Range("A1:A1000")
        If InStr(c.Value, "VALUE") Then
            c.EntireRow.Delete()
        End If
    Next
```

This will only delete a few of the rows within the specified range, what could the problem be?

Comment: You will probably next to reserve the loop to go from the last cell for first cell. Otherwise it'll skip rows that get deleted.

Comment: You shouldn't use a For ... Each loop in order to remove elements within the collection, as you're modifying the number of elements in that collection within the loop.  It would be better to use a For I = 1000 To 1 Step -1 loop as @Gareth mentioned.

Comment: @ChicagoMike, you can use the `For Each`, you just cannot `Delete` inside it without expecting odd behavior (e.g. skipped rows).  See the `Union-Delete` example below.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two common patterns for deleting entire rows based on a condition.  The main idea is that you **cannot delete from a collection while you iterate it**.  This means that `Delete` should not appear in a `For Each`  This is fairly standard across most programming languages and some even throw an error to prevent it.

**Option 1**, use an integer to track the rows and have it work from the end to the beginning.  You need to go backwards because it is the easy way to avoid skipping rows.  It is possible to go forwards, you just need to account for not incrementing when you delete.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithIntegerLoop()

    Dim rng_delete As Range
    Set rng_delete = Range("A1:A1000")

    Dim int_start As Integer
    int_start = rng_delete.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = int_start To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(rng_delete.Cells(i), "VALUE") > 0 Then
            rng_delete.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Option 2**, use the `Union-Delete` pattern to build a range of cells and then delete them all in one step at the end.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithUnionDelete()


    Dim rng_cell As Range
    Dim rng_delete As Range

    For Each rng_cell In Range("A1:A1000")
        If InStr(rng_cell, "VALUE") > 0 Then
            If rng_delete Is Nothing Then
                Set rng_delete = rng_cell
            Else
                Set rng_delete = Union(rng_delete, rng_cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    rng_delete.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

**Notes on the code**

For Option 2, there is an extra conditional there to create `rng_delete` when it starts at the first item.  `Union` does not work with a `Nothing` reference, so we first check that and if so, `Set` to the first item.  All others come through and get `Set` by the `Union` line.

**Preference**

When choosing between the two, I always prefer Option 2 because I much prefer to work with `Ranges` in Excel instead of iterating through `Cells` with a counter.  There are limitations to this.  The second option also works for discontinuous `Ranges` and all other variety of weird `Ranges` (e.g. after a call to `SpecialCells`) which can make it valuable when you are not sure what data you will be dealing with.

**Speed**

I am not sure about a speed comparison.  Both can be slow if `ScreenUpdating` and calculations are enabled.  The first option makes `N-1` calls to `Delete` whereas the second option does a single one.  `Delete` is an expensive operation.  Option 2 does however make `N-1` calls to `Union` and `Set`.  I assume it's faster than the first one based on that (and it seems to be here), but I did not profile it.

Final note: `InStr` returns an integer indicating where the value was found.  I always like to make the boolean covnersion explicit here and compare to `>0`.

Comment: Great detailed answer!

Comment: Very good answer, Thankyou very much!

The only problem I get is when running it i get this error:
- Additional information: Conversion from type 'Range' to type 'String' is not valid
On this line of code:
- If InStr(rng_delete.Cells(i), "APO") > 0 Then

Comment: Might mean your range is more than a single column.  Use `.Cells(i,1)` in that case instead of `.Cells(i)`.

Comment: As the rng_delete Union is more common than a non-union it will speed the code up if you change the order of the IF test.

Comment: @brettdj, Flip the `If-Else` with a `Not` or put the inner `If` (`...Is Nothing...`) on the outside?  I don't want to `Set rng_delete` until I know there is a match so I don't think the latter change is viable.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use loops, use a method such as `AutoFilter`

```
Sub Recut()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng1 = ws.[A1:A100]

ws.AutoFilterMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rng1
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*VALUE*"
      `assuming A1 is a header, and checking for at least 1 match on the filtered string
       If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
End With
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So far as I can tell, `AutoFilter` ignores the size of the range that it is being applied to.  That is, calling `[A1:A20].AutoFilter` with data in rows 21:40 also will extend the `AutoFilter` to all 40 rows.  This is fine except in the case where the filter returns no results.  The deletion will then be done on the original range `[A1:A20].EntireRow` (really `A2:A21`) which is entirely hidden so it will all get deleted.  Normally the `AutoFilter-Delete` works because Excel will only delete visible rows when applied to a filtered range.  If all go hidden, then it doesn't work and deletes all.

Comment: @byron - no the range doesnt extend.

Comment: If you put data in `A1:A40`, and apply the AutoFilter to `A1:A20`, do you get filtered rows all the way to row 20 or row 40?

Comment: Row 20. But you make a good point re deleting all rows if there are no matches - will address

Comment: Very odd.  With a column of `1`s (so that no rows match `*VALUE*`) from A1:A40, if I run your code with range A1:A20, and stop it after the `AutoFilter` is applied (don't delete), rows 2:40 are hidden.  Excel 2013.

Comment: Yes, but rng1 only applies to A1:A20 - not A1:A40

Comment: Ahhh. Ok.  I just meant that the _AutoFilter_ extends not the underlying defined `Range`.  Sorry for the confusion.  I was really trying to test if `.Offset(1)` would delete one row of extra data if it was there.  Instead I saw that it deleted everything if no rows matched!  Your edit fixes the problem and the real thing I was testing with `Resize`.  Good stuff.