# VBA Macro, delete the row with keywords from the column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, keyword

I'm trying to write a macro for VBA that will go through one of the columns (say D), and compare names there with a list of exclusions that I will have on Sheet 2.  Then is needs to delete a row with matched word and move up the list, until entire list is clear of lines with those words.

Here as far as I got but for some reason it doesn't do anything.

```
    Sub Delete_Exeptions()
     x = 2
     Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4) <> ""
        i = 11
        Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
           If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1).Value Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4).EntireRow.Delete
           i = i + 1
        Loop

        x = x + 1
     Loop
```

this one worked faily well if someone inerested:

```
Sub Delete_Exeptions()
     x = 2
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4) <> ""



        i = 11
        Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1) <> ""


            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4).Value <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1).Value Then

            Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4).EntireRow.Delete


            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

       x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Well it's final eddit, I've changed as recomended so the first loop goes from last row to first, as I did bump into problem, when I had two exclusions in a row. But I've decided to not use other methods that were recomended instead(Match and CurentRegion) as they didnt really work for me.

```
Sub Test_Bottom_toup()

Dim str As String
Dim strArr() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1")

With ws
    lRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

x = lRow
    Do While x <> 1


    str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4)
    strArr = Split(str, " - ")
    ' This one is for my data spesifically as I had a random number before actual name, which might not be on the list of exlusions.

    i = 11

     Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1) <> ""

     If strArr(1) <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List2").Cells(i, 1) Then

     Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List1").Cells(x, 4).EntireRow.Delete


     End If

     i = i + 1
     Loop

    x = x - 1
    Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?  Where is it not doing what you expect?  Is it going through the loops appropriately? Is the conditional working appropriately?

Comment: Don't put code into a comment.  It's virtually unreadable.  Edit it into your original question.

Comment: Be aware when deleting rows.  It affects the indices.  [This answer has a couple ways to deal with that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487368/vb-excel-deleting-rows-on-a-specified-value-being-in-a-cell/30491869#30491869).  This issue comes up regularly.

Comment: You may well be better of using the Worksheetfunction Match instead of the second do loop. Secondly you are better of starting at the bottom of your list because when you delete rows your counter(x) will no longer be correct. Finally you could use the CurrentRegion method one of the cells in the range to determine how many rows you need to loop through, this will also make a for next loop possible with step -1 and saves you the trouble of checking the value of the cell against an empty value.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not gonna works(counter(x) part). I've tried multiple examples and it worked, but if you say it will cause trouble I better know now. Please and Thank you.

Comment: CurrentRegion wouldn't work as i'm putting a button on second page to clear those exeptins.